# Not able to Fetch data from Front end to the Backend in order to update my mongoDB by using Express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

My .hbs  is this running on localhost:8001/docconfirm (using hadlebars/Template Engine)

```
 <form id="login" method="GET" action="#">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Doctor's Email<span class="req">*</span> </label>
                <input type="email" name="das" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." autocomplete="off">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <br>
               <div>
                <h5 style="color:rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.588);">Choose an Updation Field:</h5>
                  <select name="egyarah" class="form-control" id="Practice" >
                    <option value="First_Name">First-Name</option>
                    <option value="Last_Name">Last-Name</option>
                    <option value="Image">Image</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    <option value="Description">Job-Description</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <br>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label> Enter the detail to be updated<span class="req">*</span> </label>
              <textarea name="baarah" class="form-control" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter meet-up address."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="mrgn-30-top">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-larger btn-block"/>
                Update Profile
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

My Backend Express Code is:

```
app.put("/docconfirm/:das", (req, res) => {
    console.log("heyyy");
        Handles.findOneAndUpdate(
    {Email:req.params.das},//trying to fetch the data got in URL and search it on my DB
      {Description: String("mm")},// trying to update it after when the search is done
        {new: true},//helps me printing the updated values
          function(err,doc){
              console.log(doc)// :( Not Working please help :)
          })
      });
```

--> I want to Fetch the data from the Front end and I want to update my database through the input given in Front End but it is not working somehow

my Schema is this - Using MongoDB(Mongoose)

```
const mongoose =require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Youraid",{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true}).then(()=>console.log("got connected from confirmdoc")).catch((err)=>console.log(err));

//creating schema for the database that has been connected by using the above code

const expSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    First_Name:{
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    Last_Name:{
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    Email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        //required: true
    },
    Image:{
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    Description:{
        type: String,
        //required: true
    }
  
  
})
const Datass= new mongoose.model("docconfirm",expSchema);

  
module.exports = Datass;
```

Comment: Your backend waits for PUT requests (`app.put(...)`), but your `<form>`  generates a GET request. (Forms cannot generate PUT requests anyway.)

Comment: Then what should my back end wait for? i have seen lot of referral videos same thing even they are using but i don't know what they are doing in the form section if you tell me what i should do with my <form> then that will help ~ Thanks

Comment: even if i use same methods it gives me:
{"index":0,"code":11000,"keyPattern":{"Email":1},"keyValue":{"Email":null}} Error.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting your `<form>` produces a request like `GET http://localhost:8001/docconfirm?das=x.y@z.com&egyarah=Email&baarah=meetup-address#`. To process this on your server, you need something like

```js
app.get("/docconfirm", function(req, res) {  // get, not put, no :das parameter
  Handles.findOneAndUpdate(
    {Email:req.query.das},  // req.query, not req.params
    {Description: String("mm")},
    {new: true},
    function(err, doc) {...});
});
```